# does FetchProfiles work with HQL?

Tags: hibernate

I can't make @FetchProfile work with HQL.

I used it succesfully with the (old) native Criteria and with session.get() API, but not with HQL.

is it normal ?

thanks
My mapping and FetchProfile definition

```
    @FetchProfiles({ @FetchProfile( name = "countryCities", 
            fetchOverrides = { @FetchOverride(entity = Country.class, 
                      association = "cities", mode = FetchMode.JOIN) }) })
    public class Country implements java.io.Serializable {

        @Id
        private long id;
        @Version
        private int version;
        private String country;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
        private Set<City> cities = new HashSet<City>(0);
    }
```

the following does not works :

```
@Override
public List<Country> findAllFetchProfileCities() {
    getSession().enableFetchProfile("countryCities");
    boolean enabled = getSession().isFetchProfileEnabled("countryCities");
    List<Country> list = getSession().createQuery("from Country").list();
    enabled = getSession().isFetchProfileEnabled("countryCities");
    return list;
}
```

the following works OK :

```
@Override
public Country findOneFetchProfileCities(Long _id) {
    getSession().enableFetchProfile("countryCities");
    Country c = (Country) getSession().get(Country.class, _id);
    return c;
}

@Override
public List<Country> findAllCriteriaFetchProfileCities() {
    getSession().enableFetchProfile("countryCities");
    return getSession().createCriteria(Country.class).list();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution to this problem as well, and found what I think is a usable work-around (not saying that this is efficient or anything!)

It involves two steps:

First add cascade REFRESH to the mapping:

```
@FetchProfiles({ @FetchProfile( name = "countryCities", 
        fetchOverrides = { @FetchOverride(entity = Country.class, 
                  association = "cities", mode = FetchMode.JOIN) }) })
public class Country implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;
    @Version
    private int version;
    private String country;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<City> cities = new HashSet<City>(0);
}
```

Then introduce a loop to refresh the objects retrieved by the list:

```
@Override
public List<Country> findAllFetchProfileCities() {
    getSession().enableFetchProfile("countryCities");
    boolean enabled = getSession().isFetchProfileEnabled("countryCities");
    List<Country> list = getSession().createQuery("from Country").list();
    enabled = getSession().isFetchProfileEnabled("countryCities");

    for (Country c:list) {
        getSession().refresh(c);
    }

    return list;
}
```

It's ugly but it got me a bit further along.

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate `Fetch` strategy is available both in the Criteria API (criteria.setFetchMode()) and HQL ("FETCH JOIN").

So when ever we writing hql we have to mention the key word "JOIN" It self there in the query, *i think*.

A bit old ,but please refer this once

[Hibernate hard facts](http://blog.frankel.ch/hibernate-hard-facts-part-6)

Comment: If i had to add the keyword "join" or "join fetch" in HQL, the fetchProfile would not be useful. FetchProfile are supposed to change the fetch plan so i don't have to. And it works prefectly when i test it on Criteria and with session.get().